# Adding custom styles to angular map using @angular/google-maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Angular 11 and @angular/google-maps, Im looking to create a map that's the same width as it's parent, but I'm only managing to get a square map (as seen in the image)
[image: Actual map display]

I'm calling the google-maps api script in my `index.html` with my API Key

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And generating the map in my `overview.component.ts`

```
    <div id='map'>
      <google-map [center]='center'></google-map>
    </div>
```

Giving it the following styles in `overview.component.scss`

```
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 400px !important;
}
```

I've also tried giving with to the `google-map` tag itself without any luck

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the width in the google-map tag.

```
<google-map width="100%"></google-map>
```

You can find more info in the docs [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/google-maps/google-map/README.md)

here is a stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-google-maps-5v2cu8?file=src/app/app.module.ts)